# How to dynamically embed pdf file to crystal report?

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

Is there a way to do a dynamic ole insert of a pdf file into a crystal
report based on  a value coming from a SQL database?

For example, I have an application in .net, back-ended by a SQL 2008 database. 
The app. has a reporting subsystem which uses Crystal Reports to allow 
users to run pre-written reports (from stored procedures) by entering 
various inputs such as date ranges, etc.

What I want to do is allow the user to enter, say, an account number
which will then be passed to a stored procedure. The procedure will
get the path to the correct PDF file and pass that to a Crystal
Report. How do I get the PDF path to the OLE Object insert??

Is this making any sense??

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Hi sir. I'm encountering the same issue. I tried to a formula to replace an OLE Object with pdf file from my server but it doesn't work. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

do you have to use pdf? the idea of adding a pdf to a crystal report makes me feel dirty all over... If possible I would use rpt files as subreports. (note the reason it makes me pale quite so much is that I come from a *nix background and still think pdf should only be used for printing)

Comment: Yes, I have to use pdf files, pdf file names are same as id and information is only with PDF file and not in database.